# Jekyll Deployment on Github Pages doesn't format correctly and links broken

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am learning about how to use Jekyll and Github recently and I am having a hard time getting my website to display correctly online but it does display correctly locally when I run:

```
jekyll serve --baseurl ''
```

My Github repo that I am working on is http://yungkickz.github.io/kingwizard

[Github Tree](https://github.com/yungkickz/kingwizard/tree/gh-pages)

Any help or hints would be super helpful.

Edit: Basically this entire website is missing the correct CSS and links are pointing to the wrong place; especially the first Home and About link as any the other links were made to just test.

My `config.yml:`

```
name: kingwizard
description: wizardly blog

paginate: 5
url: "http://yungkickz.github.io"
baseurl: /kingwizard


markdown: rdiscount
```

Also here I've added the beginning of the `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ site.description }}">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>{{ site.name }}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Arreis Style -->    
    <link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/custom-style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="{{ site.baseurl}}js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="{{ site.baseurl}}js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the source code of [your site](http://yungkickz.github.io/kingwizard/), I have noticed some issues:

1. Many of your references to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files begin with `//`. It seems like `site.baseurl` is set to `/` on GitHub for some reason, despite the setting in your config file. However, you often add addition slashes after `site.baseurl` in paths, which causes the second slash to appear.
2. Because `site.baseurl` is `/`, browers will expect to find your files at `http://yungkickz.github.io/SOME_PATH`. However, your site is actually deployed to `http://yungkickz.github.io/kingwizard`, so your links should be pointing to `http://yungkickz.github.io/kingwizard/SOME_PATH` instead.
3. Because of the 404 errors, your CSS styles are not loaded, which is why your site looks like it isn't formatted correctly.

**Before:**

```
<link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**After:**

```
<link href="/kingwizard/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank You,

In my `header.html` It basically looks like your "Before" but am I supposed to change path individually at each point in the code? I thought that `site.baseurl` would have dynamically did that portion for me so that I didn't have to.

I Apologize but I am really new to this but truly appreciate your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem with `site.baseurl`, so you should still use it. When I ran `jekyll serve --baseurl ''` locally, I noticed that the first line of the output was `Configuration file: none`. It turns out that jekyll (both locally and on GitHub) isn't loading your configuration file because it's named `config.yml`, not `_config.yml` (what it's supposed to be).

Comment: Great find! Thank you! (rookie mistake) That certainly fixed that CSS issue and many other bugs! How did you notice the `Configuration file: none` because I didn't see that when running in jekyll in terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure, I ran the same jekyll command that you did and I saw that. Maybe we're using different versions of jekyll. By the way, I noticed that you committed the `_site` directory. You may want to remove it and add it to `.gitignore`.

Comment: `.gitignore` I assume will ignore that directory but why would I want that to happen? I'll search the webs but I figured I would ask you

Comment: Yes, it will ignore it and you would want that to happen. It's even ignored in [GitHub's gitignore repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Jekyll.gitignore). `_site` is the product of your software, like a `bin` directory with executables is for a C project. You shouldn't commit these sorts of files, especially since jekyll on GitHub pages will generate `_site` for you. And there's no need to update it manually either, GitHub and jekyll will do that for you.

Comment: Completely understand, thank again! Your like a master of this ish!

edited my repo and things are coming to together well now!